# (noob) some graph theory definitions and ideas

Tags: graph-theory

I am very (extremely) new to graph theory, and I need help writing down some ideas.

So, when the $deg=2$ of all nodes, I think that the graph forms something like a polygon, but I do not think that is the correct way to describe the graph. What is a more particular way to describe it?

Also, if $deg=2$ for some number of nodes, and the rest of the nodes may or may not be connected to each other but not connected to the sub-graph where $deg=2$, then what is a term to describe this graph? I have no idea to describe such a graph, but the best way I can think of is that the subgraph of $deg=2$ forms a polygon, and the rest of the nodes are just not connected to that polygon but may be connected to each other. Again, I am really new to graph theory, so I would appreciate any help to more rigorously define these graphs.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about directed graphs (digraphs)?  For an undirected graph, there's no such thing as the in-degree or out-degree,  of a vertex, just its degree.

Comment: Ahh, never mind. I didn't realize that, and the graph is undirected. Yes, I mean degree. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As saulpatz mentions, the notion of in-degree and out-degree only make sense in the context of directed graphs, where edges are directed from one vertex to another.

I will now just talk about graphs with vertices of degree 2. Such graphs are called 2-regular graphs. Indeed, as you point out, 2-regular graphs consist of "polygons" - in graph theory we call these "cycles" rather than polygons, as in general, there are many ways of drawing any particular graph. Additionally, a portion of a graph where all vertices are connected to each other by some sequence of edges and vertices is called a connected component. See here for a more detailed discussion and some examples: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Two-RegularGraph.html .

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks! Also, is it correct to say "cycles of degree 6," or something of a similar nature?

Comment: cycles of *length* 6 is more common, I think, but the usual term is $6$-cycle, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks! Also, if you have a subgraph $G$, does saying $deg(G)=2$ imply that every vertice has degree 2?

Comment: Talking about the degree of a graph does not really make sense. The degree is defined for vertices, namely as the the number of edges incident to a vertex. I suppose you could define such a notion, i.e. saying $deg(G)=2$ meaning $G$ is 2-regular, however, I don't really see the point.